# How to generate angular library in different directory than projects?

Tags: angular

I want to generate library in packages under the root. and new application under apps.

```
repo-app /
 apps
   // angular apps here
 packages
   // angular libs here aka ngPackagr
```

I can see in `angular.json` this property: `"newProjectRoot": "projects"` but I want a different locations for apps and libs currently I have only one, when I generate application its goes to projects folder and when I generate lib its goes to projects folder.

How to do that with angular cli?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the official CLI-Docu: https://angular.io/cli/generate#library-command
At least in the docu, there is no proper solution mentioned.

**But you could also check the [CLI-Extension NX](https://nx.dev/)**

Within a NX-Workspace you have this structure out of the box:

```
workspace /
 apps
   // angular & react apps here
 libs
   // libs here
```

In addition, you can specify a specific folder, where the library should be created.(https://nx.dev/api/angular/schematics/library)

Hope this helps.

Comment: same issue i am facing whenever i add library it adds them in Projects.
i want it to be added in root which is not happening neither with command nor with nx nrwl ui.

Comment: See this blog posts: https://blog.nrwl.io/gatsby-support-custom-workspace-layouts-and-more-in-nx-9-4-497ae105bf4

You can customize your workspace layout in Nx